# Any advantage to use elongated focal window for raster Pearson's Correlation?

Tags: raster, r, spatial-statistics

I am performing Pearson's Correlation with 2 rasters (same res, size, extent), and will use a focal window, but is there any advantage or robustness to using a focal window that better reflects the raster extent and shape? e.g.

```
require(raster)
# make 2 dummy rasters and stack
r1 <- raster(xmn=0,xmx=30,ymn=0,ymx=70,res=1)
r1[] <- sample(1:3,30*70,replace = T)
r2 <- raster(xmn=0,xmx=30,ymn=0,ymx=70,res=1)
r2[] <- sample(1:3,30*70,replace = T)
s <- stack(r1,r2)

# use raster:corLocal to perform pearson test, 3x3 focal window
r.res1 <- corLocal(s[[1]],s[[2]],ngb=5,method="pearson",test=T)
# use raster:corLocal to perform pearson test, 7x3 focal window to reflect dimensions of input rasters
r.res2 <- corLocal(s[[1]],s[[2]],ngb=c(7,3),method="pearson",test=T)

# stack results and plot
res.st <- stack(r.res1, r.res2)
plot(res.st)
```

[image]

Also, does anyone know why Pearson Correlation in spatialEco divides the correlation by n-1? I thought it did not effect r ([link here](http://www2.psychology.uiowa.edu/faculty/mordkoff/GradStats/part%201/I.12%20corrltns.pdf)) but it clearly does if you use two identical dummy rasters that should be r=1 all over

Comment: The spatialEco::rasterCorrelation function does not explicitly divide the correlation by (n-1). The standard deviation assumes a sample which necessitates using (n-1) as the denominator in deriving the variance. Honestly, I would recommend using the spatialEco::raster.modified.ttest as it corrects for any spatial structure and provides a correct p-value.

Comment: Thanks for the spatialEco answer Jeffrey, i'm building up through the tests :) Any suggestions/thoughts on the focal window shape above though?